# Firebase Console - "internal error. please try again later."

Tags: firebase, firebase-console

I work with firebase 2 years without problem.
And now in firebase site i try to go dashboard or debugView and get this alert.
"internal error. please try again later."

[image]

Comment: *firebaser here* As the error says, that's an internal error, which should not normally show up on the console. I'm not sure what's causing it in this case. But there's nothing anyone here can do about this. Please [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem this week and the way I solved it was going to the project's permission [page](https://console.cloud.google.com/) and then check for you user's permission setup. My role was both *Viewer* **and** *Editor* so I changed it to **only** *Editor* and then the error was gone.

If you still have no luck you can try to clear your browser's navigation data as suggested [here](https://www.en.advertisercommunity.com/t5/forums/v3_1/forumtopicpage/board-id/Account_Management_and_Access/page/1/thread-id/2014)